# Insert rows with batch id using sqlldr

Tags: sql-loader

I am able to insert rows into a table using sqlldr with no worries. I would like to tag all rows of a file to a unique number so that I can treat them as one batch. I tried "my_db_seq.nextval" as batch id. But its not serving my purpose.

So please advise on how to create a unique batch id for entire set of rows of a file while loading using sqlldr.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your call to the sequence in a function like this:

```
create or replace function get_batch_id return integer is
     x exception;
     -- ORA-08002: sequence %s.CURRVAL is not yet defined in this session
     pragma exception_init (x, -8002);
   begin
     return my_db_seq.currval;
   exception
     when x then 
       return my_db_seq.nextval;
   end;
```

Then call it from the control file:

```
...
batch_id "get_batch_id()"
...
```

From this post: https://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/187236/.